# Charting with dates on the x-axis

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I'm tracking an asset on an hourly timeframe. I have a column for dates with a custom date format set via *Format* -> *Number* -> *Custom date and time* to something like `04/21/2023 12:00:00`. On my chart each hour shows up on the x-axis as shown in the image below. How can I modify the chart so that I only show labels for daily dates while still being able to see the asset value charted hourly?

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result of `How can I modify the chart so that I only show labels for daily dates while still being able to see the asset value charted hourly?`. Your showing image is a sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected output situation? And, in your question, what method do you want to achieve your goal using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want to see the same chart but instead of hourly labels on the x-axis I want to see one label per day, like 04/21/2023 12:00:00, 04/22/2023 12:00:00, 04/23/2023 12:00:00 etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that `04/21/2023,04/22/2023,,,` can be achieved by changing the number format. But, when the time is shown, I think that it is required to adjust the value of Major count in Horizontal axis of Gridlines and ticks. But, in that case, it will be `04/21/2023 00:00:00, 04/21/2023 12:00:00,,,` or `04/21/2023 00:00:00, 04/22/2023 00:00:00,,,`. I apologize for this.

Comment: I changed the format to '04/21/2023', '04/22/2023' ... etc. and now it seems to be working the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to change the chart type to Line Chart (there are several other supported chart types too). After I did that the correct options appeared under `Chart Editor` -> `Customize` -> `Gridlines and Ticks` -> `Horizontal Axis` for setting major and minor gridlines.

Comment: I was running into a very similar issue, but couldn't follow the advice in this answer because no "gridline" options were showing up for me. I did some searching and found a workaround to get the gridline options to show up - basically you just need to set the format to Format > Number > Automatic first, then you can edit the chart options, and then set the format back to what you want. More details here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173784/322373